# JOOQ SUM in Kotlin with custom types

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, aggregation, jooq

currently I have a converter to work with value objects in JOOQ with Kotlin.

My database has a table called `transactions` with a field type `decimal(10, 2)` called `billing _amount` and on my Kotlin code I have a simple ValueObject from DDD to wrap it up, called `BillingAmount` defined as following

```kotlin
data class BillingAmount(val value: BigDecimal)
```

As for my jooq custom converter I have the following code:

```java
public final TableField<TransactionsRecord, BillingAmount> BILLING_AMOUNT =
        createField(
                DSL.name("billing_amount"),
                org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.NUMERIC(10, 2).nullable(false),
                this,
                "",
                org.jooq.Converter.ofNullable(
                    java.math.BigDecimal.class,
                    okano.dev.jooqtesting.BillingAmount.class,
                    t -> new okano.dev.jooqtesting.BillingAmount(t),
                    u -> u.getValue()
                )
        );
```

On my repository, I'm just trying to retrieve a sum a billing amounts, but jooq is complaining that `BillingAmount` doesn't extend a `Number` class. I know that is a Java generic validation that is preventing my code from working, but there's any way around, except by extending the `Number` class, for solving this problem? I thought that the converter should be enough, but for sure I'm wrong about this.

Here's the simple query I'm trying to achieve:

```kotlin
// jooq is an instance of DSLContext
return jooq.select(sum(TABLE.BILLING_AMOUNT))
            .from(TABLE)
            .fetchSingle()
```

Any thoughts on this question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with `TABLE.BILLING_AMOUNT.coerce(BigDecimal.class)`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: That could be an answer, in fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that problems you're experiencing is just due to Java's type system.

If so, you can simply `coerce` the field to a different type for a query, like so (admittedly, muddying the query defining code):

```
BillingAmount sum = jooq
  .select(sum(TABLE.BILLING_AMOUNT.coerce(BigDecimal.class)))
  .from(TABLE)
  .fetchSingle(TABLE.BILLING_AMOUNT);
```

It's not quite the same type of result as in original query, though, because it materializes `BillingAmount` directly, and not a `Record<BillingAmount>` (because after coercion the query return type would be `Record<BigDecimal>`.

Comment: The result is not super important to me right now since I'll do some other validations, so probably wrapping in this value object makes no sense for the matter of this method. Using coerce it will force to call my converter?

I tried a different approach using cast, seems to be working, but not sure which approach is best, tho. I'll try your solution.

Comment: @WilliamOkano, no, `coerce` is more or less just to change the `T` in `Field<T>` that is perceived by compiler, I think, so the query will return `BigDecimal` if you just call `fetchSingle()`. Converter is supposed to be called (I think) because you supply a field to `fetchSingle(field)`.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can always resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) in jOOQ

```kotlin
fun alternativeSum(field: Field<*>) = DSL.field("{0}", field.getDataType(), field)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll take a look at this.

Comment: Lukas Eder, playing around with jooq, just realized that you're an official contributor hahaha.

Always nice to see that the maintainers are up to giving some advice for newbies like me :) Thanks and great job with jooq

Comment: @WilliamOkano: "An official contributor" - I like that :)